# Is the "org" keyword reserved in Apache or java or anywhere like appserver or webserver?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, struts-tags

I wanted to know that keyword "org" is specific to any java version, tomcat version, or RHEL anything? Because in one of my JSP I was using `id="org"` and while clicking on the button it was throwing an error as

```
Unable to compile class for JSP:
An error occurred at line: 53 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsps/xxxx.jsp
apache cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

```
 <html:row align="left" label="userdetails.field.label.orgs">
53: <logic:iterate name="userDetails" property="assignedOrgs" id="org"> 
 <bean:write name="org" property="name" /><br>
 </logic:iterate>
 </html:row>
```

and when I change the name of id as id="org12" then it works fine. I am able to access the page.

Is this solution right or wrong?

Comment: The list of Java keywords is in the JLS.

Comment: @EJP I was looking for "org", is this any reserve keyword anywhere?